# how to route to a different page in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a session controller like

```
def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

if you notice on successful sign in it does redirect_to user which is the show action in the User controller.

But say instead of that I have to go to the new action of user controller then how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect_to user` is just a shortcut for `redirect_to url_for(user)`, which generates the url for a given resource (`url_for`) and then redirects to it.

If you want to redirect to another url, you can use the path helper.

```
redirect_to new_user_path
```

You could also use the `url_for` helper to generate an url.

```
redirect_to url_for(:controller => "users", :action => "new")
```

Which can be shortened to

```
redirect_to :controller => "users", :action => :new
```

You can even specify an url directly (`redirect_to '/users/new'`) - *which I would not recommend, as you can't change your routing later without changing all the urls.*

### The docs

As you can see, there are many ways to specify an url to `redirect_to` in rails. [Take a look at the documentation for all of them](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to)

Comment: sounds good and what to specify if i have to go to index page of user resource?

Comment: That would be `redirect_to users_path` or `redirect_to :index`, whichever you prefer.

Comment: By the way: If you want to see all routes and the corosponding helpers, just run `rake routes` on your console.

Comment: in the shorthand notation redirect_to :new how does it knows that i am referring to user controller and not some other control? I am currently in the session controller.

Comment: Ouch. Sorry, that's my mistake. I thought your code was inside your `UsersController`, I will edit my answer.

Comment: if you notice the code above user is getting initialized using find_by_email method. so looks like it some how magically knows that the user is a resource in the line redirect_to user but what if i return more than one record?

Comment: `find_by_...` always returns the first record that matches or `nil`. I would recommend reading the [documentation on ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).

Comment: you tooke me wrong. What i meant was what if i replace it by User.all ? in that case it will return more than one. and then how this thing will behave?

Comment: It will probably raise an exception, as redirect_to does not accept arrays.

Comment: Then probably some strange kind of rails magic does weird things and somehow generates this url. I did not expect this.

Answer (score 1):

To render an action from another controller:

```
render 'users/new'
```

See:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render